# Filtering a torch dataset in R

Tags: r, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I'm trying to follow along with the book "[Deep Learning with PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf)". I am using the new R packages `torch` and `torchvision`.

On page 173, section 7.2.1 I'm just not sure how to filter this dataset to include only labels 1 and 3 (corresponding to the 0 and 2 in the book).

This is my code, and I'd like to know how to filter `transformed_cifar10` as per the code in the book. Meaning filter it so that the `transformed_cifar10$y` labels only include 1 and 3. and then remap {1,3} to {1,2}.

```
library(dplyr)
library(torch)
library(torchvision)

data_path <- "./ch7/data" # need to change this?

train_transforms <- function (img) {
  img %>% 
    transform_to_tensor() %>% 
    transform_normalize(mean = c(0.4915, 0.4823, 0.4468),
                        std = c(0.2470, 0.2435, 0.2616))
}

transformed_cifar10 <- cifar10_dataset(data_path, 
                                       train = TRUE, 
                                       download = TRUE, 
                                       transform = train_transforms)
```

This is the python code in the book:

```
# In[5]:
label_map = {0: 0, 2: 1}
class_names = ['airplane', 'bird']
cifar2 = [(img, label_map[label])
          for img, label in cifar10
          if label in [0, 2]]
```

First I thought of trying something like this but clearly it doesn't work...

`tensor_cifar10[tensor_cifar10$y == 1]`

Comment: I can't verify this at the moment (the cifar10 dataset won't download using the helper), but I suspect using `dataset_subset` will work if you provide the indices:
e.g., `cifar1_3 <- dataset_subset(transformed_cifar10, transformed_cifar10$y$item() == 1)`

Comment: For anyone who's interested in an answer to this, it was provided here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/filtering-a-torch-dataset/100520/2